# How to make continuous WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I create an Azure WebJob as shown in the following script which dequeues an item from Azure Storage Queue, and then stores it to an Azure Table. The process is finished running within 1 or 2 seconds, but it runs only few a times in a minute (and occasionally halted in approximately 10 minutes). Overall, it does not work well.

What am I missing? Maybe I'm mixing trigger job and continuous job, but it is hard to find an appropriate sample.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("started at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("s"));

        // Continuous job should have infinite loop.
        while(true){
            var host = new JobHost();
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
    }

    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueInput("blogqueue")] string json)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings    ["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Store it to Azure Table Storage
        // omitted...

        Console.WriteLine("Received JSON: {0}", json);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few comments:

1. You don't need the `while(true)` statement. `RunAndBlock` already has a while loop inside and it will block there.
2. You don't need Manually retrieve the table. You can bind to a table as shown in the samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/TableOperations/Program.cs)
3. You can bind to the storage account, you don't need to manually read the connection string from the configuration file and create the instance.

Here is an example of binding to storage account:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueInput("blogqueue")] string json, CloudStorageAccount) 
{
    ...
}
```

This is a wild guess but, from your code, it seems that the storage connection string is stored in `StorageConnectionString` in the config file. The `JobHost` expects either (1) the connection strings for runtime and data to be stored in `AzureJobsData` and `AzureJobsRuntime` (as described [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/getting-started-with-windows-azure-webjobs)) or (2) pass the connection string as parameter to the `JobHost` constructor. I think this is the reason of the crash.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question, does the binded method (ProcessQueueMessage) be executed in Triggered mode? I mean, "Countinuously triggered when queue item arrived" or "Continuously check new item by Azure own WebJob scheduler period"? My Azure Storage Explorer shows dequeue count increased higher and higher but not removed from the queue although the process succeeded. As Main method and binded method does not have concreate relationship, it is hard to guess the process.

Comment: If you use the above job in a "RunAndBlock" scenario, then your job has to be continuous. That means, the process will run all the time and it will periodically (every few seconds) poll the specified Azure queue

Comment: I changed WebJob to WorkerRole today, because WebJob seems to have low execution frequency(around 1~2 sec maybe?). I expected it had high(around 0~10 ms) frequency. Can WebJob run 0~10ms execution frequency?

Comment: The WebJob and WebJobs SDK are 2 different things, you don't need one for the other to work, so if you write your job (in .NET, javascript or whatever) to execute frequently, it will.

Answer (score 4):

Just change your publish settings in ProjectName/Properties/webjob-publish-settings.json

```
"runMode": "OnDemand"  =>  "runMode": "Continuous"
```

Answer (score 2):

For a continuous WebJob to work properly you need to enable "Always On" in the configuration tab of your website.

The "Always On" feature is only offered for Basic/Standard website plan, if it is not enabled your WebJob can go down after some time.

Comment: and what if it is deployed to kubernetes?